# How to disable laptop screen in console mode?

Tags: display, settings, console

I have an external monitor attached to my laptop. I want to disable the laptop display. This is all in console mode. I tried video=LVDS-1:d at grub, but that didn't do anything. Can vbetool switch off only one display?

long story: i7 laptop is getting heated up. It also has the nvidia/intel optimus thing in it. I need to work in console mode to find out how to disable the nvidia chip. While in console mode, the laptop shuts down due to overheating, likely due to power draw by the inbuilt display. I did rmmod nouveau to check. This is a debian box. cpu seems to be throttled at about 800MHz (due to overheating as reported in the logs). It does run 24/7 substantially cooler on Windows. Windows reports cpu speed always 100% at 2200MHz (tried to find by various methods). I could not see any evidence of the nvidia being used on windows. This leads me to believe that the overheating must be due to the screen and nvidia chip. This an Asus K53SV laptop with i7-2670QM and GEForce GT540M.

**update**: I managed to get video=LVDS-1:d to work. The laptop screen remains off. Don't know what happened last time. The nouveau module still gets loaded by gdm3, but I can remove it before or after stopping gdm. So here's something interesting: I used open hardware monitor on windows. CPU is always at 800MHz on windows (same as on linux), even though windows always reports 2200MHz. The cpu temperature is around 70C at idle, and 88C max (varies from 68C to 88C). However, on linux, it is always above 85C (85C to 88C). So what is going on in linux? How can I fix this? Is some chipset peripheral always remaining switched on? How to find out? 20C is a lot.